# Handle Multiple HTTP requests in Node JS

Tags: node.js, rest, express

Problem Statement:
Consider a node js program running with express library for REST communication.
There are multiple REST API calls and all the API's are using a single blocking resource which can run only one request at a time like serial port.

I have a situation that I receive multiple parallel requests to the API calls which inturn use the serial port for some purpose.

How do I channelize the API calls from different methods and then streamline it and then execute it one by one and then return back the response to the corresponding request ?

Code Snippet:

```
/**
 * This function is a blocking function that utilizes the serial port
 */
function request_response(shield, channel, parameter, parameterValue) {
    var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        var commandString = modbusRTURequestGenerator.modbusRTURequestGenerator(shield, channel, parameter, data, parameterValue);
        serialOUT(commandString).then(() => {
            Promise.race([serialIN(), timeOut()]).then(results => {
                resolve(results);
            });
        });
    });
    return promise;
}

/**
 * This is a GET Request API to get the parameter values.
 */
router.get("/getParameter", function (req, res) {    
    var shield = req.query.shield;
    var channel = req.query.channel;
    var parameter = req.query.parameter;

    request_response(shield, channel, parameter, undefined).then(
        (result) => {
            res.send(result);
        });
});

/**
 * This is a POST Request API to set the parameter values.
 */
router.post("/setParameter", function (req, res) {
    var shield = req.query.shield;
    var channel = req.query.channel;
    var parameter = req.query.parameter;
    var parameterValue = req.body.value;

    request_response(shield, channel, parameter, parameterValue).then(
        (result) => {
            res.send(result);
        });
});

/**
 * This is a GET Request API for Scan functionality.
 */
router.get("/scan", function (req, res) {
    var msg = {};
    var cmds_arr = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= constants.NUMBER_OF_SHIELDS; i++) {
        cmds_arr.push(i + "," + constants.SCAN_COMMAND_REGISTER);
    }

    asyncLoop(cmds_arr, function (item, next) {
        var params = item.split(",");
        var shield = params[0];
        var register = params[1];
        request_response(shield, undefined, register, undefined).then(
            (result) => {
                    msg[data] = result;
                    next();
                }
            });
    }, function () {
        res.send(msg);
    });
});
```

There are 3 kinds of HTTP REST API's: scan, getParameter and setParameter. All these 3 are accessing the request_response function. So, when I run the scan API and then trigger the getParameter API parallely, I am getting false results.

Comment: could you please provide some code snippet for your problem?

Comment: You can use some kind of queue for example https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-queue

Comment: Code snippet added.